# Node.js: How to print part of URL in ECT template

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, coffeescript

Below is app.js. The ECT file is loaded based on path.

```
var http = require('http');
var ECT = require('ect');

var renderer = ECT({ root : __dirname + '/views' });
var data = {
    title : 'Hello, world!',
    size : 'XXL'
};

var product = renderer.render('product.ect', data);
var about = renderer.render('about.ect', data);
var anypath = renderer.render('anypath.ect', data);

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var params;
  if(params = req.url.match(/^\/product\/(.+)$/)) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(product);
  } else if(params = req.url.match(/^\/about\/(.+)$/)) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(about);
  } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end(anypath);
  }
}).listen(80);
```

Without using ECT file, when browse `product/255`, I can print `You browse 255` by writing:

```
  if(params = req.url.match(/^\/product\/(.+)$/)) {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end('You browse ' + params[1]);
  }
```

But how to put `params[1]` as part of `data`?

In other words, how to print part of URL in ECT template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rendering the HTML of each page before you know any request information. The callback function you passed as argument to the `createServer` method is the callback that will be called each time you receive an request, so you will only be able to get the parameters inside that function, as you did on your second code.

So you should be able to do the following:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var ECT = require('ect');

var renderer = ECT({ root : __dirname + '/views' });

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // First element of path will be '', because the path begins with a /
  var path = url.parse(req.url).path.split('/');
  var html;
  var data = {
    title : 'Hello, world!',
    size : 'XXL'
  };

  if('product' === path[1] && path[2]) {
    data.title += ' You browse a product with the parameter ' + path[2];
    html = renderer.render('product.ect', data);
  } else if('about' === path[1] && path[2]) {
    data.title += ' You browse at about page with the parameter ' + path[2];
    html = renderer.render('about.ect', data);
  } else {
    data.title += ' You browse anything else :)';
    html = renderer.render('anypath.ect', data);
  }

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(html);
}).listen(80);
```

Comment: I added `thepath : ''` in `data` and `data.thepath += + path[2];` in `if` rules. So that I can print `<%- @thepath %>` in ECT template. Do you think it is good practice?

Comment: If it's about presentation logic, it will probably be better to let the views decide what to do with `thepath`. In this way you will be [separating presentation from content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content).

Answer (score 1):

Use node.js URL parser like :
http://nodejs.org/api/url.html

```
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(req, res){
  console.dir(url.parse(req.url));
});
```

Comment: It print out pathname, path, href, etc in the console. But still have no idea how to use it as `data`